# Listener not being invoked

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, selectonemenu

I have a problem with listener not being invoked in the below selectOneMenu

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="Country" value="#{bean.country}">
   <f:ajax render="inputId" listener="#{backingBean.clearMethod}" />
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="-Select One-" itemValue="_" noSelectionOption="true"/>
     <f:selectItems value="#{optionValues['countryList']}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:inputText id="inputId" value="#{bean.city}"/>
```

The optionValues resolver is used to resolve a country list options from an xml file.
It has USA, Canada and Mexico. My problem is when I change the option from USA to Canada or Select One to USA, the `clearMethod` is invoked.  But When I change the option from USA to Select One, the `clearMethod` is not invoked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the `itemValue` attribute in the `noSelectionOption`. It will problably cause a validation error and therefore the listener is not called.

Try to remove the `itemValue` attribute.

(Btw: in your code the `value` attribute of `selectOneMenu` is not bound to a backing bean field. Or is it a typo?)

Comment: Removing the itemValue didn't help, but it worked when I changed the value from `_` to something else such as `SelectOne` it works

Comment: If I change the `itemValue` when the form is submitted it accepts the `SelectOne` value and the page is submitted.